# Computing the Remainder of Division of An Unknown Polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is as follows.

> After dividing $p(x)$ by $(2x-1)$ and $(x+1)$, the resulting residuals are $6$ and $3$, respectively. Find the residual when $p(x)$ is divided by $(2x-1)\times(x+1)$.

In this situation, it is difficult to guess what the quotient will be because neither the quotients nor $p(x)$ is given in the problem. What would be the best way to solve this easily?.

Do I need to use Ruffini formula or Horner or long division algorithm? The answer which would help me the most is the one which does include an explanation if any of those are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$p(x)=(2x-1)(x+1)q(x)+bx+c.$$
Compute $b$ and $c$ using $p(1/2)=6$ and $p(-1)=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the remainder of the division by the $2^{nd}$ degree polynomial $(2x-1)(x+1)$ must have degree $\lt 2\,$, so it must in fact be linear: $\;p(x)=(2x-1)(x+1)q(x) + ax +b\,$. Write it for $x=1/2$ and $x=-1\,$, note that you know $p(1/2)$ and $p(-1)$ already (*why?*) , then solve the two equations for $a,b$.

Comment: The same answer :)

Comment: @MathLover Seconds late, I know ;-) not much room here to write a hint without giving up the full answer.

Comment: @dxiv Why $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=-1$, Is it because the two factors must equate to zero as means to have only the residual?. What's the value of $p(1/2)$ and $p(-1)$? Are they related to $6$ and $3$? How? That's where I'm lost.

Comment: `because the two factors must equate to zero as means to have only the residual?` Right. `What's the value of p(1/2) and p(−1)?` Write the long division $p(x)=(2x-1)\cdot f(x) + g$ and let $x=1/2$ to find the constant $g$. Or, use [little Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) directly.

Comment: To execute the long division I need to know the polynomial which is not given. Or could it be that can be done but I am not understanding what you mean?. The little Bezout's theorem as far I have understood means that if a polynomial is divided by $x-a$ then $f(a)=0$. How does this is used to relate with the other data?. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The *form* $p(x)=(2x-1)\cdot f(x)+g$ is guaranteed by the [Euclidian division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) regardless of $p(x)$. The little Bezout's theorem (at the previous link) states that "*the remainder of the division of a polynomial f(x) by a linear polynomial x-a is equal to f(a)*".

Comment: I'm stuck at trying to understand why $p(1/2)=6$. The rest I get it, since the $g$ wouldn't it be $ax+b$?. The closing phrase from the article in wikipedia mentions if only if $f(a)=0$ that's why I thought it would be of use in the solution.

Comment: You have $p(x) = (2x-1) \cdot f(x) + g$ by Euclidean division, where the divisor $2x-1$ is of degree $1$ and therefore the remainder $g$ is of degree strictly $\lt 1$ i.e. it is a constant. Let $x=1/2$ then $p(1/2) = (2 \cdot 1/2 - 1) \cdot f(1/2) +g = 0 \cdot f(1/2) + g = g\,$. So $\,g\,$, which again is the remainder of the division by $2x-1$, is equal to $6$

Comment: That's more clear But in my opinion to follow what you did it was unnecessary to work with the long division (although I do not know if you were referring to the algorithm). As mentioned lines above the rest is easy. But to me the key was to notice the degree of the remainder is one less the divisor.